# How to Test an Instance Variable in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am having trouble testing an external instance variable with Rspec. While there are some similar questions on StackOverflow, I haven't been able to find a solution for testing it in a GET request (since this is for an API).

I have an ApiController method that does something along these lines:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def auth(token)
    @user = User.find_by_token(token)
  ...
end
```

Then, I have a request spec that looks something like this:

```
describe 'GET /v1/friends' do
  it 'returns friends' do
    ApiController.any_instance.stub(:auth)
    get "v1/friends"
    ...
  end
end
```

I get an error that says `undefined method XXX for nil:NilClass` that stems from the fact that the @users instance variable isn't being passed into the GET request.

I have tried using `assigns()` and that doesn't seem to work, while not stubbing the auth class isn't an option for a different reason. And, simply setting the instance variable doesn't seem to work, because I've read that Rspec assumes that it's its own variable rather than one used in the test (?).

Is there any way to set the @user instance variable to a fake user when running the GET request?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried `assigns(:user)`? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and receive the same nil error. When testing the API using curl, it works properly, so there's nothing wrong with the controller method itself, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up refactoring quite a bit of other code to run the authentication method that creates the instance variable in the actual controller. I don't believe there is a way to set a variable in Rspec for use in a GET request.

When using an integration test to test `authenticate_with_http_token`, you'll need to include it like so in the GET request:

`get '/v1/path-for-api', nil, authorize: 'Token token=#{user.token}'`

From there, the variable was properly set now and I was able to test the requests.